# Heroku deploy don't find Java Servlet

Tags: java, heroku

I have deployed a web app on Heroku.

It starts in an index.jsp which has a form which sends a post request to a Servlet.

The servlet should save the data and then redirect via response.redirect("/example.jsp").

The problem is that when I submit the form, the URL changes to the Servlet name and Heroku doesn't find it.

I don't know what I need to configure.

On the local server (*Tomcat 10.0.23*) it works fine. It doesn't show the name of the Servlet in the URL.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**src folder:**

[image]

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletDatabase</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.gabit.dev.makeawish.controllers.ServletDatabase</servlet-class></servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletDatabase</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Error:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Heroku uses an old version of Tomcat by default, so in this case I replaced Jakarta references with Javax in the Servlet and pom.xml.